# Auto labelling in doccano

Tags: nlp, annotations, data-annotations, doccano

I’m getting into manual annotation for NLP , found a cool tool named DOCCANO for annotation which has auto labelling feature.
If anyone know how to setup auto annotation using custom REST api request.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @druskacik is very useful. just one minor edit: the values need to be wrapped in double-quotation marks.

In the example case:

```
    [
        {% for entity in input %}
            {
                "start_offset": "{{ entity.start_offset }}",
                "end_offset": "{{ entity.end_offset}}",
                "label": "P-B"
            }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for **Sequence Labeling** project:

Let's say we have custom API that requires text to be classified send in a request body, like this:

```json
{
    "text": "example text"
}
```

When setting up Auto Labeling in Doccano, in the second screen **Set parameters**, set up your API url and other optional parameters (e.g. authentication headers), then use `text` variable as shown in the screenshot, using `{{ text }}` format. Every time the auto labeling API is called, it will send text in place of this variable.

[image: Using text variable]

In the next step, **Set a template**, we need to specify a mapping template for mapping the API response to doccano specific format. In this case, we could use this:

[image: mapping template]

It uses `jinja` format, here is mapping template from the screenshot:

```
[
    {% for entity in input %}
        {
            "start_offset": {{ entity.start_offset }},
            "end_offset": {{ entity.end_offset}},
            "label": "P-B"
        }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
]
```

Finally, in the last step, we just map labels from the previous step to labels that were created before in the doccano project. This should be straightforward.

[image: mappings]

Then just click **Finish** and we are good to go.

To enable auto-labeling, open any datapoint in the **Dataset** tab and toggle the switch in the window that shows up after clicking **Auto Labeling** button. From now on, every time you open an un-approved data row, it will automatically use auto-labeling to label the text for you.